# Is there a LPN estimator like LWE?

Tags: cryptanalysis, lwe

I recently studied the LPN problem and BKW algorithm for solving LPN problem. Several papers deal with the concrete parameters of LPN to be secure against BKW algorithm, but I cannot measure the concrete complexity of BKW algorithm. The papers provided the concrete parameters when the memory space is bounded by $2^{60}$ or $2^{80}$ while I cannot understand how to set those parameters.

Is there a LPN estimator? or estimator of BKW algorithm? If not, how to measure the concrete parameters of BKW algorithm?

Comment: Which paper do you have in mind? As far as I know, some parameters are suggested in https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/078, and their security estimation algorithm can be found in https://github.com/Memphisd/LPN-decoded.

Comment: As I know, the code implemented the BKW attack, but what I want is just estimate the concrete security for simplicity.

Comment: No, the code is for estimating the security. See the bottom of page 23 in the paper. (In particular, the code does not take any concrete LPN instance as its input.)

Comment: @Hhan Thanks you!